# How do I resume Yeoman generator script after an error?

Tags: yeoman, mean

I ran the official yeoman MEAN.JS generator and it failed to generate the app. The error was a wrong python version. I installed python 2.7.10 and would like to continue my build.

What is the command to resume the build?